# Return NULL if cannot contact Linked Server

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

We use a Shared Dataset within our SQL Reporting Services to return Branding Information for reports from 2 SQL Servers, one located at head office and one at the satellite branch.

This is a select distinct from a table of the same name on both SQL Servers an example is below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Brand] FROM [MyDB].dbo.Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT [Brand] FROM [MY-LINKED-SERVER].[MyDB].dbo.Table2
```

A problem occurred where the satellite office internet was down, this meant that the shared dataset failed because it couldn't contact the 'linked server' is there a way I could return 'NULL' or another value if the SELECT statement from the Linked Server time's out or doesn't respond?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
BEGIN TRY
exec sp_testlinkedserver [MY-LINKED-SERVER];

SELECT DISTINCT [Brand] FROM [MyDB].dbo.Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT [Brand] FROM [MY-LINKED-SERVER].[MyDB].dbo.Table2
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
SELECT 'Handle Me'
END CATCH
```